# Programatically making changes to an file using Excel prompts the user to save changes

Tags: c#, .net, excel, csv

I have the following method which just removes rows from a file if a cell in the row contains a particular value:

```
foreach (Excel.Range row in workSheet.UsedRange.Rows)
{
    foreach (Excel.Range cell in row.Columns)
    {
        if (cell.Value == null)
            continue;

        string colVal = cell.Value.ToString().ToLower();

        if (colVal.Contains(".zip") || colVal.Contains("bin") || colVal.Contains("debug") || colVal.Contains("release"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(colVal);
            rowIndices.Add(rowIndex);
        }
    }

    rowIndex++;
}

rowIndices = rowIndices.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList();

foreach (int i in rowIndices)
{
    string rangeFormat = String.Format("{0}:{1}", "A" + i, "F" + i);
    workSheet.get_Range(rangeFormat, Type.Missing).Delete(Excel.XlDeleteShiftDirection.xlShiftUp);
}

workBook.Save();
```

I passed in a path to a .csv file, and when the code gets to the last line in the snippet above, a dialog pops up asking if you'd like to save changes, as if you manually opened Excel, made a change and then tried to close it. If I open Excel and save the .csv as an .xlsx and re-run this tool on the file it does not prompt the user.

Anyone know how I can prevent this? I use WinMerge to generate a Report (which saves as CSV) on 2 folders then run this tool on the report. Would be nice to not have to manually re-save the report as an "actual" Excel type.

Comment: I think you can use the [`SaveAs` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.saveas(v=vs.120).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) rather than the `Save` method, passing in `Type.Missing` for any parameters you do not wish to set.  Additionally you could try setting `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.[Your Excel App Variable Name].DisplayAlerts = False` just prior to saving the workbook.  You may want to re-enable it after.

Comment: @Soulfire using `SaveAs` still prompted the user, but setting `DisplayAlerts` as you suggested fixed the issue. If you'd like to submit that as an answer I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `DisplayAlerts` property to `False` prior to saving.

Like so:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application.[Your Excel App Variable Name].DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: Much appreciated! Never would have guessed such a flag exists.